# Show that if T commutes with all M then T is a multiple of identity

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $X$ be Banach and let T $\in \mathcal{L}(X)$ s.t $TM=MT$ $\forall $ M $\in \mathcal{L}(X)$. Then $T$ is a multiple of the identity.

I did proof by contrapostition, but Im not 100% confident Im doing it right;

Suppose $T$ is not a multiple of the identity then there is an $x$ s.t $Tx \ne ax$ $\forall$ $a$. Hence span{x} is not invariant under $T$. I.e there is an subspace of $X$ for which is not invariant under $T$.

Pick $M$ s.t span{x}=$X$ is invaranit under $M$, the image of M invariant under T and the image of T is invariant under $M^{-1}$. Then

$TMX \subset MX \subset X \ne TX \subset MTX$

Q.E.D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be more explicit when choosing $M$. There are several conditions you have on $M$, you have to show that there is an $M$ having all the properties you want.

Comment: Am I in the clear besides that?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists $x$ such that $x$, $T(x)$ are independent. Let $M'$ defined on $Vect(x,T(x))$ by $M'(x)=x$ and $M'(T(x))=2T(x)$. The Hahn Banach theorem allows to extend $M'$ to a bounded operator $M$ of $X$, $MT(x)=2T(x), TM(x)=T(x)$, this implies that $T(x)=x=0$. Contradiction.

If $T(x)=c_xx, c\in R$ for every $x\in X$, suppose $x,y$ independent $T(y)=c_yy, T(x+y)=c_{x+y}(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)=c_xx+c_yy$ this implies $c_{x+y}=c_x=c_y$ thus $T$ is a multiple of the identity.